# Effective query than AND operator in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle database. The below query is not working as expected.

```
select * 
from cst_cust_attributes 
where attribute_value='event' 
and attribute_value='reg'
and attribute_value != 'guest';
```

I need all the customer data who has only attribute_values in both 'event' and 'reg', and not in 'guest'. But I am getting the correct output. The records consist of mixed of customer data who are having all 3 attribute_values.

Below is structure of the table

```
Name            Null?    Type          
--------------- -------- ------------- 
ORGANIZATION_ID NOT NULL NUMBER(19)    
CUST_ID         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(32)  
ATTRIBUTE_ID    NOT NULL NUMBER(19)    
ATTRIBUTE_SEQ   NOT NULL NUMBER(10)    
ATTRIBUTE_VALUE NOT NULL VARCHAR2(254) 
ACTIVE_FLAG     NOT NULL NUMBER(3)     
CREATE_DATE              DATE          
CREATE_USER              VARCHAR2(254) 
UPDATE_DATE              DATE          
UPDATE_USER              VARCHAR2(254)
```

Comment: It is impossible for a single row to have the `attribute_value` column with the value of both `event` and `guest` at the same time. Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table; the `INSERT` statements for some sample data; and the expected output for your sample data.

Comment: I have downvoted this question because it turned from one thing into another and another so the question is not helpful at this point and it is unclear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use a query like below which uses exists to check for all conditions

```
select * 
from cst_cust_attributes c
left join cst_mail n on c.CUST_ID   =n.CUST_ID   
where c.attribute_value='event' 
and exists 
( 
select 1 from cst_cust_attributes b where c.CUST_ID   = b.CUST_ID  
and b.attribute_value='reg'
)
and not exists
(
select 1 from cst_cust_attributes a where c.CUST_ID   = a.CUST_ID  
and a.attribute_value = 'guest'
)
```

Comment: This will only get the rows where `attribute_value='event'` and will not output the rows where `attribute_value='reg'` (it would only check that they exist).

Comment: As questions says ' need all the customer data ' and since I have joined queries based on CUST_ID, both event rows will have same customer data. There is nothing which is missed out here

Comment: I believe this is where OP should have been more precise...

Comment: The question states "i need all the customer data". Yes, this would get the `CUST_ID` but it would not get "all the customer data" as it will not return the `attribute_value='reg'` customer data.

Comment: @DhruvJoshi i need join another column mail_id from another table cst_mail using joins.to mention the corresponding email id for the cust_id.please tell where to insert the left join

Comment: @HappyMan replace `from cst_cust_attributes c` with `from cst_cust_attributes c left join newtable n on c.cust_id=n.cust_id`

Comment: @DhruvJoshi not working could you please edit in the your above answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `COUNT` analytic function and conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT a.*,
         COUNT(CASE attribute_value WHEN 'event' THEN 1 END)
           OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id) AS num_event,
         COUNT(CASE attribute_value WHEN 'reg' THEN 1 END)
           OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id) AS num_reg,
         COUNT(CASE attribute_value WHEN 'guest' THEN 1 END)
           OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id) AS num_guest 
  FROM   cst_cust_attributes a
)
WHERE  num_event > 0
AND    num_reg   > 0
AND    num_guest = 0;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
INSERT INTO cst_cust_attributes (
  organization_id,
  cust_id,
  attribute_id,
  attribute_seq,
  attribute_value,
  active_flag
)
SELECT 1, 'C1', 1, 1, 'event', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'C1', 2, 1, 'reg',   1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'C1', 3, 1, 'guest', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'C2', 1, 1, 'event', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'C2', 2, 1, 'reg',   1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'C3', 1, 1, 'event', 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ORGANIZATION_ID | CUST_ID | ATTRIBUTE_ID | ATTRIBUTE_SEQ | ATTRIBUTE_VALUE | ACTIVE_FLAG | CREATE_DATE | CREATE_USER | UPDATE_DATE | UPDATE_USER | NUM_EVENT | NUM_REG | NUM_GUEST |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | C2 | 1 | 1 | event | 1 | *NULL* | *NULL* | *NULL* | *NULL* | 1 | 1 | 0 |
> | 1 | C2 | 2 | 1 | reg | 1 | *NULL* | *NULL* | *NULL* | *NULL* | 1 | 1 | 0 |

> could you please tell me where to add the below condition and `trunc(CREATE_DATE) >='05-MAY-2019' AND trunc(CREATE_DATE)<='13-APR-2022' group by cust_id;`

Adding a `GROUP BY` does not make sense if you are trying to return all the rows.

As for the date range, it depends on whether you want to check if:

- `event` and `reg` and not `guest` values are only within that range; or
- any `event` and `reg` and not `guest` rows exists, either inside or outside that date range, and then return the rows that are within that range.

For the former, the you would add a `WHERE` clause inside the sub-query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT a.*,
         COUNT(CASE attribute_value WHEN 'event' THEN 1 END)
           OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id) AS num_event,
         COUNT(CASE attribute_value WHEN 'reg' THEN 1 END)
           OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id) AS num_reg,
         COUNT(CASE attribute_value WHEN 'guest' THEN 1 END)
           OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id) AS num_guest 
  FROM   cst_cust_attributes a
  WHERE  create_date >= DATE '2019-05-05'
  AND    create_date <  DATE '2022-04-13' + INTERVAL '1' DAY
)
WHERE  num_event > 0
AND    num_reg   > 0
AND    num_guest = 0;
```

For the latter, the filters would be added to the outer query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT a.*,
         COUNT(CASE attribute_value WHEN 'event' THEN 1 END)
           OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id) AS num_event,
         COUNT(CASE attribute_value WHEN 'reg' THEN 1 END)
           OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id) AS num_reg,
         COUNT(CASE attribute_value WHEN 'guest' THEN 1 END)
           OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id) AS num_guest 
  FROM   cst_cust_attributes a
)
WHERE  num_event > 0
AND    num_reg   > 0
AND    num_guest = 0
AND    create_date >= DATE '2019-05-05'
AND    create_date <  DATE '2022-04-13' + INTERVAL '1' DAY;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
INSERT INTO cst_cust_attributes (
  organization_id,
  cust_id,
  attribute_id,
  attribute_seq,
  attribute_value,
  active_flag,
  create_date
)
SELECT 1, 'C1', 1, 1, 'event', 1, DATE '2022-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'C1', 2, 1, 'reg',   1, DATE '2022-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'C1', 3, 1, 'guest', 1, DATE '2022-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'C2', 1, 1, 'event', 1, DATE '2022-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'C2', 2, 1, 'reg',   1, DATE '2022-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'C3', 1, 1, 'event', 1, DATE '2022-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'C4', 1, 1, 'event', 1, DATE '2022-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'C4', 2, 1, 'reg',   1, DATE '2022-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'C4', 3, 1, 'guest', 1, DATE '2018-01-01' FROM DUAL;
```

Then the former query returns the `C2` and `C4` rows and the latter query returns only the `C2` rows (as a `reg` value exists for `C4` but it is outside of the date range).

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=053aa1682228e59be829b772dd8d2479)*

---

> I want join the column `MAIL_ID` from another table `cst_mail` using joins. to refer the corresponding `maild id` for the `cust_id`

Something like:

```sql
SELECT a.*,
       m.mail_id
FROM   (
         SELECT a.*,
                COUNT(CASE attribute_value WHEN 'event' THEN 1 END)
                  OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id) AS num_event,
                COUNT(CASE attribute_value WHEN 'reg' THEN 1 END)
                  OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id) AS num_reg,
                COUNT(CASE attribute_value WHEN 'guest' THEN 1 END)
                  OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id) AS num_guest 
         FROM   cst_cust_attributes a
         WHERE  create_date >= DATE '2019-05-05'
         AND    create_date <  DATE '2022-04-13' + INTERVAL '1' DAY
       ) a
       JOIN cst_mail m
       ON (a.cust_id = m.cust_id)
WHERE  num_event > 0
AND    num_reg   > 0
AND    num_guest = 0;
```

Comment: @MTO it was a wonderful .thanks so much .i validated and got the desired output.

Comment: @MTO could you please tell me where to add the below condition and ---trunc(CREATE_DATE) >='05-MAY-2019' AND trunc(CREATE_DATE)<='13-APR-2022'
group by cust_id; ----

Comment: @HappyMan Updated. Although it would help if you [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71937170/edit) to include a [MRE] with your sample data and the corresponding expected output.

Comment: @MT0 great really happy for your immediate response.on last thing, i want join the column MAIL_ID from another table cst_mail using joins.to refer the corresponding maild id for the cust_id.could you please help with that?? i really admire your efforts

Comment: @HappyMan Just `JOIN` the extra table: `SELECT a.*, m.mail_id FROM (...) a JOIN cst_mail m ON (a.cust_id = m.cust_id) WHERE ...`

Comment: @MT0 CAN  u please edit in the above iam little confusing in this stage...please

Comment: @MT0 its showing error invalid identifier

Comment: @HappyMan You have not provided a [MRE] and the bits you are asking about now are beyond the scope of your original question. It is not productive to go back and forth in comments so I suggest that you [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and provide a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements and a complete description of the problem and your errors so that we have all the information to debug it. As for the invalid identifier, you have two options `CUST_ID` or `MAIL_ID` as those are the only new columns referenced; I suggest you debug it and check those.

Comment: noted @MT0.Thanks for the help.

Comment: @HappyMan I've added an alias for the sub-query that was in my original comment but got missed in the question edit; that might fix the error but if it doesn't then you will need to check that the identifiers being referenced exist and the spelling matches your tables. Beyond that, you would need to provide a [MRE], as mentioned before.

Answer (score 0):

So you basically just want attribute_value to be "event" and "reg" ?
So why just dont use the following select ?

```
select * from cst_cust_attributes where attribute_value in('event','reg');
```

Comment: OP: "i need all the customer data who has only attribute_values in both 'event' and 'reg'" . Also OP: "And not in 'guest'". So your query does not help...

Comment: But when its in 'event' and 'reg', it automatically cant be anything else ?

Comment: It is not only one row of data for one cust_id. There are more than one rows for every cust_id. Check the data @MTO prepared...